# What is the PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID in the Paypal integration development

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

What i am doing ,

simply i am copying code from the https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/ site .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, "");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
```

For this i have created two accounts in the paypal , 
one for `receiver` 
second for `sandbox test account` ( because i am developing an app and using this id )
So , after implmenting this , i have got , with the help of `tushar.2april@gmail.com`).

**Receiver account** :

with the help of `tushar.pandey1991@gmail.com`

**Sandbox account** :

After login with `tushar.2april@gmail.com` i have created business and personal account .

iam2ndstan@yahoo.com ( `personal account` )

tushar.2april-facilitator@gmail.com (`business account` )

**Problem , what i am facing** :

in which  basis i define

`:-` `PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID`

``` :-``PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID ```

`PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL` : `tushar.pandey1991@gmail.com'

`:-` if i am attempting any hit & try and after it i am getting Json also 
[image]

`:-` i will Email ( for proof ) automatically or i have to implement the code for it .

Edited Section :

```
07-01 17:35:09.068: I/dalvikvm(841): Could not find method android.app.Activity.getActionBar, referenced from method com.paypal.android.sdk.C.a
07-01 17:35:09.068: W/dalvikvm(841): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8: Landroid/app/Activity;.getActionBar ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
07-01 17:35:17.608: I/dalvikvm(841): Could not find method android.view.View.setBackground, referenced from method com.paypal.android.sdk.af.a
07-01 17:35:17.608: W/dalvikvm(841): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 311: Landroid/view/View;.setBackground (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)V
07-01 17:35:36.598: W/KeyCharacterMap(841): No keyboard for id 0
07-01 17:35:36.598: W/KeyCharacterMap(841): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
07-01 17:35:49.257: I/dalvikvm(841): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841): {
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):     "payment": {
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         "short_description": "hipster jeans",
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         "amount": "8.75",
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         "currency_code": "USD"
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):     },
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):     "client": {
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         "platform": "Android",
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         "paypal_sdk_version": "1.0.2",
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         "product_name": "PayPal Android SDK; ",
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         "environment": "mock"
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):     },
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):     "proof_of_payment": {
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         "adaptive_payment": {
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):             "timestamp": "2013-07-01T12:06:11+0000",
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):             "payment_exec_status": "COMPLETED",
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):             "app_id": "_FAKE_APPLICATION_ID_",
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):             "pay_key": "AP-70M68096ML426802W"
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):         }
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841):     }
07-01 17:36:19.308: I/paymentExample(841): }
```

Comment: @YogeshTatwal , please see my edited Section .

Comment: @YogeshTatwal , Can u please explain : what is , PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID
PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID

& how to find them .

Comment: usse it  PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();
  payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal("" + amount));
  payment.setCurrencyType("EUR");
  payment.setRecipient("Id");
  payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
  Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, this);
  startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);

Comment: APP-80W284485P519543T use this app id

Comment: like this  PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T",
PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

Comment: still any more doubt please refer https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/SampleApp/src/com/paypal/example/paypalandroidsdkexample/MainActivity.java

Comment: @YogeshTatwal , at , monday you just missed the line that Paypal payment style is divided in two category .
Us developer .
non-Us developer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "");
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, ""); 
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
```

`EXTRA_PAYER_ID` : means , who will get the transferred money from your account ( buyers , your personal account ) .

`EXTRA_CLIENT_ID` : generated , from the website when you are creating an app , and registering it there in the web .

`EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL` : means , business account of yours .

[image]

Comment: When I try to create new app from this url https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications and Integration type=Mobile SDK than it returns "We’re sorry, but something went wrong while creating the application. Please try again."

Comment: let me know is any wrong process I made. Same issue found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058007/paypal-unauthorized-device

Comment: @BhavinChauhan , refer this : http://hutofandroid.blogspot.in/2013/07/paypal-implementation-in-android.html